# List index errror

Tags: python, list

I have created a program which reads a file line into a list. When i run the code below, i see that there is a list with elements inside it.

```
dogs_list_player = []
dogs_list_computer = []

with open("dogs.txt") as f:
    for i in range(Y):
        dogs_list_player.append(f.readline().splitlines())
        print(dogs_list_player)
    for i in range(Z):
        dogs_list_computer.append(f.readline().splitlines())
        print(dogs_list_computer)
```

The result is:

```
[['Tim']]
[['Tim'], ['Bob']]
[['Tim'], ['Bob'], ['Jess']]
[['Tim'], ['Bob'], ['Jess'], ['Bess']]
[['Tim'], ['Bob'], ['Jess'], ['Bess'], ['Tess']]
[['Dom']]
[['Dom'], ['Tom']]
[['Dom'], ['Tom'], ['Will']]
[['Dom'], ['Tom'], ['Will'], ['Ben']]
[['Dom'], ['Tom'], ['Will'], ['Ben'], ['Joe']]
```

But the issue arises when i add this part of code:

```
dogs_list_player = []
dogs_list_computer = []

with open("dogs.txt") as f:
    for i in range(Y):
        dogs_list_player.append(f.readline().splitlines())
        print(dogs_list_player)
    for i in range(Z):
        dogs_list_computer.append(f.readline().splitlines())
        print(dogs_list_computer)

class Dog_card: 
    name  = ""
    friendliness = ""
    intelligence = ""
    exercise = ""
    drool = ""

    def printing_card(self):
        prnt_str = "Name:%s \nIntelligence:%s \nExercise:%s \nDrool:%s" %(self.name, self.friendliness, self.intelligence, self.exercise, self.drool)
        return prnt_str

player_card = Dog_card()
card_count = 0
player.name = dogs_list_player[0]#i think this is where the issue is happening
```

the result of this code is:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try printing `dogs_list_player` or `len(dogs_list_player)` just to check where you think the issue is...
btw, your class should actually instatiate its attributes inside a `def __init__(self):` function, that way you can actually have multiple instances with different attributes

Comment: what is `Y` - what is `Z` - both are used but nowhere set to anything in your code. You use classmembers, read about https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects - first ones are shared between instances, you do not want that for multiple dogs - they all would have the same name.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @pekapa I have tried printing dogs_list_player and i have shown the result of that above, but for some reason i keep getting the error

Answer (score 1):

your Dog_card class has some errors :
you forget "friendliness" parameter in the string that is in printing_card method and also you have not any constructor in your class .

```
class Dog_card:

def __init__(self):
    self.name = ""
    self.friendliness = ""
    self.intelligence = ""
    self.exercise = ""
    self.drool = ""

def printing_card(self):
    prnt_str = "Name:%s \nIntelligence:%s friendliness:%s \nExercise:%s \nDrool:%s" %(self.name, self.friendliness, self.intelligence, self.exercise, self.drool)
    return prnt_str
```

this shoud be work .